# Как вызвать метод исходного класса из унаследованного в VBA?

Tags: ms-access

Есть исходный класс(class module) CSVUtility

```
Public Function readCSVFile(ByVal fileName As String) As String()
...
End Function

Public Function retrieveRecordFromCSV(ByVal csvString As String, ByVal delim As String) As Dictionary
...
End Function

Public Sub fillData(ByRef d As Dictionary, ByRef TmpAr() As String)
End Sub
```

И есть унаследованный класс(class module) CSVUtilityInherited

```
Implements csvUtility

Private Sub csvUtility_fillData(d As Scripting.IDictionary, TmpAr() As String)
...
End Sub

Private Function csvUtility_readCSVFile(ByVal fileName As String) As String()
...
End Function

Private Function csvUtility_retrieveRecordFromCSV(ByVal csvString As String, ByVal delim As String) As Scripting.IDictionary
...
End Function
```

Как вызвать из унаследованного функции исходного класса?

Answer (score 0):

В Акцесе нет наследования в полном смысле этого слова, есть только интерфейсы, которые содержат только объявления методов, которые нужно будет реализовать в классах, которые объявлены как `Implements` от класса-интерфейса.
Т.к. класс-интерфейс не может содержать реализацию метода, то и вызвать такой метод нельзя.